# How to get IP address without a plugin?

Tags: conditional, ip-address

I just want to run a couple of conditionals depending on a visitor's IP address. How would I do that?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

To make use of your visitors IP address, use `{{ craft.request.getIpAddress() }}` in Craft 2.5. In Craft 3.x, there is `{{ craft.app.request.userIP }}`.

Comment: 2021 reference: `craft.request.getIpAddress()` has been deprecated. Use `craft.app.request.userIP` instead.

Answer (score 9):

From PHP:

```
if (craft()->request->getIpAddress() == '255.255.255.255')
{
    ...
}
```

Note [from the docs](https://buildwithcraft.com/classreference/services/HttpRequestService#getIpAddress-detail) that this is a "best guess" and can easily be spoofed, so you shouldn't use it to hide any sensitive information.

We currently don't expose that method at the template level, but we probably should. I'll add that on the Craft 2.3 branch.

If you want to hack it in before then, you can open up `craft/app/variables/HttpRequestVariable.php` and add:

```
public function getIpAddress()
{
    return craft()->request->getIpAddress();
}
```

Then from a template you'd use:

```
{% if craft.request.getIpAddress() == '255.255.255.255' %}
    ...
{% endif %}
```

Just note that there is a chance that a 2.2 update could overwrite that file at any time.

UPDATE: No hack is required since Craft 2.3.2615.

Comment: Thanks Brad - I'd searched the docs using 'ip ' and should've used 'ipa'!

Comment: Actually, is there any reason {{ craft.request.getIpAddress() }} would be empty?

Comment: If your server isn't populating `$_SERVER['REMOTE_ADDR']`?

Comment: This is strange. In a simple PHP file I can echo $_SERVER['REMOTE_ADDR'] but if I put {{ craft.request.getIpAddress() }} at the top of my layout template, nothing is output.

Comment: And have tried this on two sites on different server setups, too.

Comment: Gah, sorry.  Looks like we don't expose that to the template level. I'll update my answer.